# Guide for Replication in MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

I want to set up a Replication between two different computers that run `MS SQL Server 2008`, the master runs on Windows Vista, and the slave will run on `Windows XP`.

I´ve done this before between two MySQL-servers.

Question: Does anyone have a guide for `**Replication in MS SQL Server 2008**`?

Answer (score 1):

I found this site to be helpful setting up Replication you may have already seen it but in case you haven't:

https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-replication-basic-setup-and-configuration/